# How to add a test external bank account to the test environment at Banno digital.garden-fi?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I need to add an external test account to the Banno test environment (https://digital.garden-fi.com/). I saw that it is using Mastercard's `finicity` to link external accounts, which according to the following link https://docs.finicity.com/test-the-apis/ should work using username:demo and password:go but I am getting this error: [image: error linking test account]

I'm assuming garden-fi is using a "production" user, so we can't link test accounts.
Does anyone know a solution for this problem? I need to test the features I'm developing with an external account in the Garden-fi test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Linking test users from the [Garden demo institution](https://digital.garden-fi.com/) with Finicity isn't supported.

### Longer answer

In this case, the reasons behind that limitation are based on the fact that "Production" is in the eye of the beholder.

From Jack Henry's standpoint, the *Garden* environment runs *production* code but for a *demo* institution. The 'demo institution' nature means that that users in *Garden* are test users (per [Accessing the Digital Toolkit](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/accessing-the-digital-toolkit/)).

From Finicity's standpoint, the users described in https://docs.finicity.com/test-the-apis/ are test users. Finicity doesn't have a way to determine that *Garden* users are test users and can't differentiate them from production users at a real institution.

- As an aside, it would be interesting to have that level of cooperation between dev/test environments across companies in the *future*, but that's not in place *today*.